# Add FadeIn & FadeOut to a Popup JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a popup box which will open on click function and it works perfectly fine except fadein/fadeout effect.

Can Anyone tell me how to add fadein/fadeout effect to the below code, please?

```
function openPopUp() {
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";

}

function closePopUp() {
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have added `jquery` tag, I assume it's fine with jQuery.

```
function openPopUp() {
    $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(500); // "500" is not required. "400" is the default value
}

function closePopUp() {
    $("#myOverlay").fadeOut(500);  // "500" is not required. ""400 is the default value
}
```

More information:

- [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
- [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery Solution**
Jquery can do it more easily using jquery

```
function openPopUp() {
    $("#myOverlay").fadeIn("slow");
}

function closePopUp() {
    $("#myOverlay").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

more details on jquery [FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [Fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

---

**Javascript solution** 
you need to set a callback to a function that will change the opacity of your div

```
var done = true;
fading_div = document.getElementById('myOverlay');

function openPopUp() {
        if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '1') {
            done = false;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'in')", i * 5);
            }
        }
}

function closePopUp() {
        if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '0') {
            done = false;
            for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
                setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'out')", (i - 100) * -1 * 5);
            }
        }
}

function function_opacity(opacity_value, fade_in_or_fade_out) 
{
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 100) {
        done = true;
    }
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'out' && opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        done = true;
    }
}
```